# How to add a listener to a python server

Tags: python

I have a simple script to run a python server

I would like to run a code when a request is sent to the server.

I'm wondering if I should use a handler or something similar.

Here is my script"

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer

PORT = 8888
server_address = ("", PORT)

server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
handler.cgi_directories = ["/"]
print "Serveur actif sur le port :", PORT

httpd = server(server_address, handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: What does your server **do**? Do you have CGI scripts, or are you trying to run just any HTTP Python web-server? If the later, use Flask or something like it

Comment: What exactly do you want? If you just want to call a function in your code from the web then you should have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.html (especially the server side). If want to genereate html or other stuff and put it in a website then you should have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html (better: https://docs.python.org/3/library/wsgiref.html#examples ) or better use a framework like eg http://bottlepy.org/

Comment: Have a look at [Multi-threaded TCP Socket Server](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1530/sockets/24255/multi-threaded-tcp-socket-server). Change the `handle_client` and `client` functions to fit your needs.